# filter and group by array of tags in column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following example, how do I keep only rows that have `"a"` in the array present in column `tags`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["val", "tags"], data=[[5,["a","b","c"]]])
df[3<df.val]            # this works
df["a" in df.tags]      # is there an equivalent for filtering on tags?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using sets is intuitive.  Then you can use `>=` as set containment

```
df[df.tags.apply(set) >= {'a'}]

   val       tags
0    5  [a, b, c]
```

---

A Numpy alternative would be

```
tags = df['tags']
n = len(tags)
out = np.zeros(n, np.bool8)
i = np.arange(n).repeat(tags.str.len())
np.logical_or.at(out, i, np.concatenate(tags) == 'a')

df[out]
```

---

Per [@JonClements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760758/filter-and-group-by-array-of-tags-in-column-of-a-dataframe#comment92455511_52760855)

You can use `set.issubset` in a `map` (very clever)

```
df[df.tags.map({'a'}.issubset)]

   val       tags
0    5  [a, b, c]
```

Comment: Could use: `df.tags.map({'a'}.issubset)` here

Comment: Nice one!  I've added it.

Comment: Should be quite fast as well as it doesn't require converting the lists into sets first... but I haven't timed anything :)

Comment: Yeah, that is a big benefit.   But, not as golf friendly.  (For everyone else, I'm joking, I don't really care about golf friendliness)

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```
df1 = df[["a" in x for x in df.tags]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `apply` with a lambda function which tests if `'a'` is in arg of lambda:

```
df.tags.apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)
```

Result:

```
0    True
Name: tags, dtype: bool
```

This can also be used to index your dataframe:

```
df[df.tags.apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)]
```

Result:

```
   val       tags
0    5  [a, b, c]
```